# jquery - live and delegate failed here

Tags: jquery

The following codes worked before but would not work again except I put alert after the ajax call, I've use both delegate & live but it didn't work still.

```
function getAns(val) {
var value;
value = $("input[name=ans"+val+"]:checked").val();
$.post('ajax.php', {val:value}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
//only works with this alert
alert('done'); 
});
```

}

Comment: Two words: Get. Firebug. [http://getfirebug.com/](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: Two better words: Get. Chrome.

Comment: @MattAnderson - One better word? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you had an additional `});` in your function. You are also using `val` as an object key when it holds a value from the function argument. Not sure if that was intentional, but try this:

```
function getAns(_val) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'val=' + $("input[name=ans" + _val + "]:checked").val(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus + ' -- ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there's an omitted line between variable declaration and the assigning of the selected input, thats the form submit line ($("form#myform").submit(function() {), - thats explains the extra "})". I've tried you suggestion, it still didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: See updated code. Try `$.ajax()` method and make sure you are using the latest version of JQuery